# specify the return type without an intermediary variable

Tags: typescript

Sometimes typescript can't infer the return type of a lambda or a method, and I want to specify it by hand to gain type safety.

The problem occurs for instance when using promises or a bit more sophisticated callbacks (for instance with the `parsimmon` parsing library).

I did not find a way to specify the type of the return variable to get type checking except by creating a local variable:

```
interface ITest {
    x: number;
    y: string;
}

// type checks, i'd prefer it doesn't
function f1() {
    return {x:5} as ITest;
}

// type checks, i'd prefer it doesn't
// (I understand it's a cast, just to show also that doesn't help)
function f2() {
    return <ITest>{x:5};
}

// correctly fails to type-check
function f3() {
    const x: ITest = {x:5};
    return x;
}
```

is there another way to get type checks without creating a local variable? I'm aware of course that I could type `function f4(): ITest` but my use-cases look more like this:

```
return P.string(" for ")
    .then(P.takeWhile(c => c !== ' ').skip(P.string(" in ")))
    .chain(value => P.takeWhile(c => c !== ' ')
           .chain(array => parseNgOptionsTrackBy().atMost(1)
                  .map(trackBy => {
                      // variable created solely for type-checking
                      const r: NgOptionsData = {
                          select: expressions.select,
                          label: expressions.label,
                          value: value,
                          array: array,
                          trackexpr: trackBy ? trackBy[0] : undefined
                      };
                      return r;
                  })));
```

or:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // some code, then variable created solely for type-checking
    const result: ViewInfo = {
        fileName: fileName,
        ngModuleName: ngModuleName,
        controllerName: controllerName,
        controllerViewInfos: viewInfos};
    resolve(result);
});
```

In other words I'm deep in some lambda and specifying a return type is not that simple.

**UPDATE** I see there is some skepticism that typescript is actually unable to infer `resolve` for promises. Luckily my app is OSS. I made a commit demonstrating the problem in some branch:
https://github.com/emmanueltouzery/ng-typeview/tree/so_question

Check [the last commit on that branch](https://github.com/emmanueltouzery/ng-typeview/commit/6a2cee89f4170da9f7a970716b1e84e060296e53). As you can see, I removed one field from the structure i'm filling (I want a build error!!) but it builds just fine. And I *did* specify the return type of the function, `Promise<ControllerScopeInfo>`.
[This is type-unsafe](https://github.com/emmanueltouzery/ng-typeview/blob/6a2cee89f4170da9f7a970716b1e84e060296e53/src/controller-parser.ts#L248-L253).
If you want to build, you must run `npm install` and then `tsc`. Though presumably you can just inspect the source and the tsconfig and trust me on the building or not.

Comment: Why can't you use `function fn(...): Promise<ViewInfo>` in your scenario?

Comment: I answered there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41323066/specify-the-return-type-without-an-intermediary-variable#comment69849897_41323131  -- that doesn't help.

Comment: Interesting. Does this happen to you in other cases that don't involved returning a `Promise`?

Comment: yes for instance the other example which I gave with deep lambdas with the parimonn library. Also, even using `flatMap` with `immutable.js` will completely confuse the type-checker which infers `{}`... I found typescript's type inference extremely disappointing sadly.

Comment: did anyone mention the Promise is Generic and expects **T** to be specified in the constructor , or defaults to {} ...that could explain why the example code work as designed

Comment: @Dan I checked it you are right. changing to `new Promise<ConcreteType>` fixes the issue in the case of promises. That said, I also have the other example, my first one, with parser combinators. There is no `new` constructor there that I see where I could put the type :-( But that's helpful, I'll use that, thank you!

Comment: @Dan although it helps only for one of the two cases that I highlighted, if you add an answer with this explanation to this question, I'll mark it as answering the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested

In one of the above examples:

```
    function x() /*: Promise<{}>*/ {
        // declared as Promise<{}>    
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {                
            // ViewInfo assignable to {} 
            resolve(
                <ViewInfo>  {
                fileName: fileName,
                ngModuleName: ngModuleName,
                controllerName: controllerName,
                controllerViewInfos: viewInfos}
            );
        })
    };
```

The inferred function is

```
()=> Promise<{}>
```

due to:

[Promise](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es6.d.ts#L1329) is **Generic** and expects **T** to be specified in the constructor,
or defaults to Promise<{}>
resolving ViewInfo is also legal
based on [Typescript structural subtyping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html),
is assignable to {}

that could explain why the example code work as designed

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve({
        fileName: fileName,
        ngModuleName: ngModuleName,
        controllerName: controllerName,
        controllerViewInfos: viewInfos
    } as ViewInfo);
});
```

---

#### Edit

That is weird, and might be a bug because if you add an optional property:

```
interface ViewInfo {
    fileName: string;
    ngModuleName: string;
    controllerName: string;
    controllerViewInfos: ViewInfo[];
    dummy?: any;
}
```

And then do:

```
return Promise.resolve({
    fileName: "fileName 2",
    ngModuleName: "ngModuleName 2",
    controllerName: "controllerName 2",
    dummy: 3
});
```

You'll get an error:

> Type 'Promise<{ fileName: string; ngModuleName: string;
>   controllerName: string; dummy: number; }>' is not assignable to type
>   'Promise'.
>
> Type '{ fileName: string; ngModuleName: string; controllerName:
>   string; dummy: number; }' is not assignable to type 'ViewInfo'.
>
> Property 'controllerViewInfos' is missing in type '{ fileName: string;
>   ngModuleName: string; controllerName: string; dummy: number; }'.

There's a chance that it's by design, but I can't think of a reason right now.  Try to file an issue, if you do please share the link.

In the meanwhile, you can create factory functions for these types you wanna return:

```
function viewInfoFactory(fileName: string, ngModuleName: string, controllerName: string, controllerViewInfos: ViewInfo[]): ViewInfo {
    return {
        fileName,
        ngModuleName,
        controllerName,
        controllerViewInfos
    }
}
```

In the function you'll get the type safety you're after, also, depending on your code, it can make it more readable.

Comment: this is my `f1()` example. Not good enough, it warns if you add a field which is not in the interface, but not if you don't list all the fields from the interface.

Comment: Check my revised answer

Comment: thanks for the tip about the factory. That would work, but I think a local variable is less verbose. So you think the non-inference for promises could be a bug... Interesting. That said there are many cases where TS-inference is disappointing, not only this one, and I think the TS team knows about this. But maybe I'll manage to report it -- if I do I will paste the link here yes.

Comment: A local variable might be less verbose, but it's another line in a function that might already be complicated. By delegating the object creating to a function the original function size will be smaller and thus more readable. Typescript still has issues, but they are being fixed pretty fast.

Comment: i could always use a class with "public" fields in the constructor and "new". But for now I'll leave it as it is, unless someone else has a better solution. And yes, I'm hoping the situation will improve in future TS versions and I can remove this kludge then if nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare return type of some promise like `Promise<string>`

```
function returnStringPromise(): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve("string");
    })
}
```

or

```
return <Promise<string>> new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve("string"));
```

or

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve("string")) as Promise<string>;
```

Comment: for the `Promise<string>`, sadly typescript's type inference is not powerful enough to infer the type of resolve. So that doesn't help.

Comment: @EmmanuelTouzery, I usually write return type after parameters `function (params): returnType` and have no problem. You can try to add extra parentheses like `return (<ITest>{x:5});`, TypeScript sometimes need this extra help. If that does not help, I suspect your configuration to not strictly check undefined members. I'm using tightest configuration with `allowImplicitAny: false` and `strictNullChecks: true` and in cases such is yours, I have no problem with type checks.

Comment: I use the same configuration as you. Making a full test program is maybe impractical. With promises I guarantee you typescript is not capable of the inference.

Comment: I have updated my question with a link to the full program which should not build but does.